# Stop Select2 from closing dropdown after Select All ticked

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

I'm trying to stop my select2 dropdown from closing after I click on a 'Select All' checkbox.  After reading the posts I see I can get away with forcing a
    .select2('open');
but this is a hack and visually poor.

Following the posts I've also tried to use
    stopPropagation() in the 'Select All' click event but it seems to be ignored (else I'm not using it right).  I've yet to see an example in the posts of a case where the dropdown does stay open after selecting all options.

Anyone any ideas?

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/css/select2.min.css"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"></script>


<body class='bodyClass'>

  <div class="CountryDropContainer">

    <div id="Container_selectAll">
      <label id='#Outer_selectAll'>
  <input id="selectAll" type='checkbox'>
  <span></span>
  All
</label>
    </div>

    <select id="CountryBoxesContainerID_prodn" name="CountryBoxesContainerID_prodn" class="form-control select2-multiple" multiple="multiple">

<option class="myEuropeCountries" value="UN208a" title="Denmark" >Denmark</option>
<option class="myEuropeCountries" value="UN233a" title="Estonia" >Estonia</option>
<option class="myEuropeCountries" value="UN246a" title="Finland" >Finland</option>
<option class="myEuropeCountries" value="UN348a" title="Hungary" >Hungary</option>
<option class="myEuropeCountries" value="UN352a" title="Iceland" >Iceland</option>

</select>
  </div>
</body>
```

.

```
$(function() {

  var S2MultiCheckboxes = function(options, element) {
    var self = this;
    self.options = options;
    self.$element = $(element);
    var values = self.$element.val();
    self.$element.removeAttr('multiple');
    self.select2 = self.$element.select2({

      allowClear: true, 
      placeholder: options.placeholder,
      closeOnSelect: false,

      templateSelection: function() {
        return self.options.templateSelection(self.$element.val() || [], $('option', self.$element).length);
      },
      templateResult: function(result) {
        if (result.loading !== undefined)
          return result.text;
        return $('<div>').text(result.text).addClass(self.options.wrapClass);
      }
    }).data('select2');
    self.select2.$results.off("mouseup").on("mouseup", ".select2-results__option[aria-selected]", (function(self) {
      return function(evt) {
        var $this = $(this);

        var data = $this.data('data');

        if ($this.attr('aria-selected') === 'true') {
          self.trigger('unselect', {
            originalEvent: evt,
            data: data
          });
          return;
        }

        self.trigger('select', {
          originalEvent: evt,
          data: data
        });
      }
    })(self.select2));
    self.$element.attr('multiple', 'multiple').val(values).trigger('change.select2');
  }

  // -----------------

  $.fn.extend({
    select2MultiCheckboxes: function() {
      var options = $.extend({
        wrapClass: 'wrap'
      }, arguments[0]);

      this.each(function() {
        new S2MultiCheckboxes(options, this);
      });
    }
  });


});



// ======================================

// Initialise dropdown
$(function() {

  //---------



  //---------


  $('#CountryBoxesContainerID_prodn').select2MultiCheckboxes({

    // placeholder: "",
    closeOnSelect: false,
    width: "auto",
    placeholder: '',
    escapeMarkup: function(markup) {
      return markup;
    },

    templateSelection: function(selected, total) {
      return ("Select Country" + ' ' + "") + selected.length + (" of ") + total + ("\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0");
    },


  })


  //----------------------


  // When select2 is opened, show 'Select All' chkbx
  $('select').on('select2:open', function(e) {
    $('#Container_selectAll').css('display', 'block');
    $('#Container_selectAll').show();
  });


  // When select2 is closed
  $('select').on('select2:close', function(e) {
    //$('#Container_selectAll').hide();
  });



  // Detect click of an option 'ON'
  $("#selectAll").click(function() {

    if ($("#selectAll").is(':checked')) {

      $("#CountryBoxesContainerID_prodn > option").prop("selected", "selected");
      $("#CountryBoxesContainerID_prodn").trigger("change");
      //$('#CountryBoxesContainerID_prodn').select2('open');

    } else {
      $("#CountryBoxesContainerID_prodn > option").removeAttr("selected");
      $("#CountryBoxesContainerID_prodn").trigger("change");
      //$('#CountryBoxesContainerID_prodn').select2('open');
    }
  });


});
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/x4eexqnc/

Comment: You should add your selectAll button to select2 container, not outside.

Comment: Is that likely to solve all the issues?

Comment: About 99%, because when you add that in select2 container, select 2 container won't close on any click.

Comment: Many thanks - I'll check out how to do that

Answer (score 1):

you can try this:

HTML:

```
<select multiple id="hihi">
       <option>1</option>
       <option>4</option>
       <option>3</option>
       <option>2</option>
 </select>
```

JS:

```
$('#hihi').select2({
    closeOnSelect: false
});
```